# Best way to make 122 buttons with Image

Tags: vb.net, button

I have big problem.
I have 122 buttons and they must have our image , manually it will take a "year" . I want to do this automatically , example Button1 is named 1 and I have in resources photo named 1.png , button2 is named 2 and resources 2.png . How to fill all this buttons  automatically? 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Explain "fill buttons" and "must have our image". Show us the code you have.

Comment: I should add this .. for future reference .. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: I have no code,I have only buttons and tab pages,it's app for showing counters in LOL ,and I need 122 buttons with champ icons.My english is bad so this thread looks like a ... . But thanks next time I will read and use this advices to make normal thread. :)

Comment: No problem. It was just a pointer towards asking good questions and avoiding downvotes in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the buttons in a loop is easy, but adding unique handlers for each button is the pain. You would be better creating one button, copying it and pasting it 121 more times. Then, in your program create a sub like the one below to add the background images to each button.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddBackgroundToButtons
End Sub

Private Sub AddBackgroundToButtons()
    For Each control As Object In Me.Controls
        Dim btn As Button
        If TypeOf control Is Button Then
            btn = CType(control, Button)
        Else
            Continue For
        End If
        Dim btnNum As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(btn.Name.Substring(6), btnNum) Then
            If btnNum >= 1 AndAlso btnNum <= 122 Then
                Dim img As Image = New Bitmap("K:\png\" & btnNum.ToString & ".png")
                btn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center
                btn.BackgroundImage = img
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

if the buttons are inside a Groupbox or some other container then you might need to change the `Me.Controls` to something like `Me.GroupBox1.Controls`